# Проверка на пустой символ в аффинном шифре

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Реализую аффинный шифр. Нужно, чтобы слова можно было вводить только без пробела. Но не получается реализовать корректную проверку на пустой символ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы если в тексте был пробел хоть один, то программа бы не срабатывала.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int a;
int b;

string encryption(string m) {
    string text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {
        if (m[i] != ' ') {
            text = text + (char)((((a * (m[i] - 'A')) + b) % 26) + 'A');
        }
        else {
            text += m[i];
        }
    }
    return text;
}

string decryption(string c) {
    string text = "";
    int a_invers = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        flag = (a * i) % 26;
        if (flag == 1) {
            a_invers = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
        if (c[i] != ' ') {
            text = text + (char)(((a_invers * ((c[i] + 'A' - b)) % 26)) + 'A');
        }
        else {
            text += c[i];
        }
    }
    return text;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    cout << "Введите число a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите число b: ";
    cin >> b;

    if ((a == 0 || a == 2 || a == 4 || a == 6 || a == 8 || a == 10 || a == 12 || a == 13 || a == 14 || a == 16 || a == 18 || a == 20 || a == 22 || a == 24) || (a >= 26)) {
        cout << "Число a некорректно! Возможные значения: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23 и 25" << endl; 
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }

    string msg;
    cout << "Введите сообщение заглавными буквами: ";
    cin >> msg;

    /*for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
        if (msg[i] != ' ') {
            cout << "Вы ввели пробелы, повторите ввод текста без пробелов!" << endl;
            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
    }*/

    string c = encryption(msg);
    cout << "Зашифрованное сообщение: " << c << endl;
    cout << "Расшифрованное сообщение: " << decryption(c);

    ofstream out;
    out.open("d:\\1\\shifr.txt");
    if (out.is_open())
    {
            out << "Зашифрованное сообщение: " << c << endl;
            out << "Расшифрованное сообщение: " << decryption(c) << endl;
    }


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну так `cin >> msg;` и не читает пробелы. `cin` читает до первого пробела. Возможно Вам нужно читать так: `getline(cin, mesg);`. Так будет считана вся строка до нажатия Enter. Ну а потом уже проверять есть ли в строке пробелы.

Comment: Ну или после `cin >> msg;` проверяйте следующий символ в потоке. Если он `\n` - значит считали всю строку без пробелов. Иначе наткнулись на пробельный символ.

Comment: @EOF, если вместо cin использовать getline(cin, mesg); то строка, где просится ввести сообщение выводится пустой и туда ничего нельзя ввести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, как вам уже заметили, вы не считываете текст целиком, а только первую последовательность символов до пробельного знака (в том числе таба и `\n`). Так что для начала вам нужно изменить код считывания данных на что-то вроде:

```cpp
std::getline(std::cin, msg);
```

Но я больше предпочитаю подобный вариант:

```cpp
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cin}, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}, std::back_inserter(msg));
```

Во-вторых, проверку на наличие пробельных символов легко реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений. Это будет что-то вроде:

```cpp
  std::regex checkRegex{"^[^\\s]+$"};
  if (std::regex_match(msg.begin(), msg.end(), checkRegex) == false) {
    std::cerr << "message is invalid" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

Хотя я бы лучше выбрал другую регулярку, вроде `^[A-Z]+$`

Comment: Спасибо за подробные объяснения.